# Use B2C Sign-In-Policy from .Net Client App

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to use the Sign-in policies configured in Azure AD B2C with custom screens. I'm using the ADAL C# library.

```
var clientid = "aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa";
var redirecturi = "http://AppName";
var resourceid = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_EMailSignInPolicy";
var authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant.onmicrosoft.com";

var authcontext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
var result = authcontext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceid, clientid, new Uri(redirecturi), new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto)).Result;
```

If I run this I get the Microsoft OAuth Login, but instead I want the B2C policy endpoint. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve this by switching from ADAL to MSAL.Net (Microsoft.Identity.Client library), which is currently in preview.

```
var clientid = "aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa";
var policy = "B2C_1_Policy";
var redirecturi = "appname://appname/redirect/path";
var authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/tenant/{policy}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize";
var pca = new PublicClientApplication(clientid, authority) { RedirectUri = redirecturi };
string[] scopes = new[] { };

var result = pca.AcquireTokenAsync(scopes).Result;
```